# Firefox and Chrome Display "top: -5px differently"

Tags: html, css

Using Google Web Toolkit, I have a DIV parent with a DIV and anchor children.

```
<div class="unseen activity">
  <div class = "unseen-label"/>
  <a href .../>
</div>
```

With the following CSS, Chrome shows the "unseen label" slightly below the anchor. which is positioned correctly in both Chrome and FireFox.

However, FireFox shows the label in line with the anchor.

```
.unseen-activity div.unseen-label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

and

```
.unseen-activity a {
    background: url('style/images/refreshActivity.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 2px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

Please tell me how to change my CSS so that Chrome render the label centered to the anchor. However, I need to keep FireFox happy and rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center your `unseen-label` class set a width on the `unseen` class, then for your `unseen-label` set `margin:0 auto;` along with a width and align it as you need to. I'm not in firefox so can't comment on what you're seeing. But you can set your `unseen` class to `position:relative;` then your `unseen-label` position to absolute which will let you position it anyplace using negative top right left bottom spacing. Then also get rid of the display inline-block

Comment: You did solve the problem that I posted. However, I'm using Google Web Toolkit. After I made my changes to my core.css file, my run-time web app still exhibits the ugly behavior I described. Another team member mentioned that my CSS might be overridden by another CSS tag. Your proposed changes worked using Firebug, but I'm having a CSS/GWT problem too. Got any ideas?

Comment: It would be easier if you can give the URL so I can look in firebug as well as developer tool to get the CSS correct.